# Confusion about homoclinic points and orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have three main questions.

1. A homoclinic orbit of a continuous dynamical system is an orbit that connects a saddle fixed point to itself. This does not make sense to me. A fixed point is a fixed point. If you start at a fixed point and traverse along an orbit, and come to back the fixed point, then it wouldn’t be a fixed point.
2. A homoclinc point is where the stable and unstable manifolds of the same fixed point intersect. It is well known that if there is one homoclinic point there are infinitely many. Why? Consider a trivial case when the manifolds are just curves, specifically parabolas. There will be at most four intersection points.
3. What do these two facts above have to do with each other? In other words, why are they both called homoclinic?

Thanks!